# Mimic paragraph headers types with Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

Assume you have paragraph title like that:

- H1 - Header1
- H1.1 - SubHeader 1.1
- H1.2 - SubHeader 1.2
- H1.3 - SubHeader 1.3

I wanna if possible to mimic it to Object calls.
So if i call `H1`, it will return the title `Header1`, but if i call `H1.1`
it will return `SubHeader 1.1`.

I thought to create an Object like so:

```
var H1 = {
    1: SubHeader 1.1,
    2: SubHeader 1.2,
    3: SubHeader 1.3,
}
```

the problem is how to implement the call for `H1`?

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong problem. You have an actual HTML paragraph right? Just query it: `paragraph.querySelector("h2").textContent` etc. If you don't I'd opt for a more markup-like representation of it rather than storing the headers all at once.

Comment: It`s not related to DOM, i wanna create a representation of paragraph headers like Object, if it even possible.

Comment: Property names in JS can't start with numbers if using the dot operator - you'll have to use H1[1]

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 ways of doing it. Choose the one that fit your needs

```js
//Nested objects
var headers = {
  "1": {
    "": "Header 1",
    "1": "Subheader 1.1",
    "2": "Subheader 1.2",
  },
  "2": {
    "1": "Subheader 2.1"
  }
};

console.log(headers["1"][""]);
console.log(headers["1"]["1"]);

//Each header has is own object
var h1 = {
  "": "Header 1",
  "1": "Subheader 1.1",
  "2": "Subheader 1.2"
};

var h2 = {
  "1": "Subheader 1.2"
};

console.log(h1[""]);
console.log(h1["1"]);

//One object to rule them all
var headersBis = {
  "1": "Header 1",
  "1.1": "Subheader 1.1",
  "1.2": "Subheader 1.2",
  "2.1": "Subheader 2.1"
};

console.log(headersBis["1"]);
console.log(headersBis["1.1"]);
```

Comment: `H1.1`, is the required call, not `H['1.1']`

Comment: @FelixMosheev Sorry that was not clear because you provided an example that do not match this. If you want the syntax `H["H1.1"]` use the answer of @MirkoVukušić

Comment: @FelixMosheev so you want to call it with H1.1 and not H["1.1"] nor H[1.1]? I don't think that's possible because you cannot refer to object property names which are numeric without brackets in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should construct your object like this:

```
var headers = {
    "H1" : "Header 1",
    "H1.1" : "SubHeader 1.1",
    "H1.2" : "SubHeader 1.2",
    "H1.3:" : "SubHeader 1.3"
}
```

Then use it like `headers["H1"]` or `headers["H1.1"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can not meet your requirement a you are defining the `object`. For you requirement you can use below object

```
var H = {
'1': "Header 1",
'1.1': "SubHeader 1.1",
'1.2': "SubHeader 1.2",
'1.3': "SubHeader 1.3"
 }
```

And simply call them like

```
 H['1'], H['1.1'], H['1.2']
```